# Sonata Admin custom query in configureListFields

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am stuck on this for several hours.

I have admin class to list all categories and in one table column there are related products (Product entity): [Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao91g.png)
Related code:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name')
            ->add('products') // Entity Product, @ORM\OneToMany
            ->add('ord')
    ;
}
```

What I need to do is hide inactive products from being listed based on "(boolean) product.active" but I can't figure it out. I know about "createQuery" method but it doesn't work. When I generate SQL and run the query directly it works but here it looks like I can use ProxyQuery only to filter Category and then all Products are queried in separate query (and this separate query I am not sure how to change).

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);

    $q = new ProxyQuery($query->join(sprintf('%s.products', $query->getRootAlias()), 'p')
            ->andWhere('p.active = :act')->setParameter('act', true));

    return $q;
}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type of your field to null or entity  and add a [query_builder option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) to adapt the query used :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
        ->add('products', null, array(
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                 return $er->createQueryBuilder('qb')
                           ->leftjoin('qb.products', 'p')
                           ->where('p.active = :act')
                           ->setParameter('act', true)
             }
     ));
}
```

I didn't test it with a oneToMany relation.

There are some information in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013504/how-to-get-the-defined-field-in-sonataadmin-query-builder)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I still can't make it work. It looks like 'query_builder' is somehow not used. I tried put die(); in that function and nothing happen.

Comment: Be sure to include the whole path to EntityRepository, not only the name:) It worked like a charm for me